# javascript toggle appear button that doesn't need 40 javascript files for 40 of the same buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a JavaScript button that can toggle show and hide. It is meant to reveal a column of answers.

My old button worked badly because I needed 40 javascript files if I wanted 40 groups of buttons and their answers.

I think something has to be done with universalising the replace bit in the variable but I don't know much javascript.

I have also since recoded the html to have the answers instead in a table column.

This is the three tables I have designed. The button is meant to reveal all the answers only in that column.

[image]

This was the (non table) previous code:

(html)

```
<div>
    <h5>
        <button class="RevealToggle" id="RevealStage1Ex1"> Reveal Answer </button>
    </h5>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p> the passeport
            <textarea></textarea> <span class="AnswerStage1Ex1">le passeport</span>
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>
            <textarea></textarea> <span class="AnswerStage1Ex1">la valise</span>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(js)

```
window.onload = function() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#RevealFrenchStage1Ex1");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
      var id = this.id.replace(/RevealStage1/, "AnswerStage1");
      var answers = document.querySelectorAll("." + id);
      for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        answers[i].style.display = answers[i].style.display == "inline" ? "none" : "inline";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The new table code looks something like:

(html)

```
<td class="FrenchAnswerAlign">
    <h6><button class="RevealToggle" data-stage="1Ex1">Reveal Answer</button></h6>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><p>le passeport</p></li>
            <li><p>l'hôtel</p></li>
            <li><p>la valise</p></li>
            <li><p>une station</p></li>
            <li><p>une leçon</p></li>
            <li><p>un chéquier</p></li>
            <li><p>une personne</p></li>
            <li><p>les journalistes</p></li>
            <li><p>les prix</p></li>
            <li><p>de la bière</p></li>
            <li><p>du vin</p></li>
            <li><p>des lettres</p></li>
            <li><p>des autobus</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Currently, when I make a new exercise, I need to make a brand new JavaScript button file that includes a Brand new ID for the answers which are to be toggled visible on/off.

Comment: Use for loops to iterate through things, instead of writing the same logic 40 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be UNIQUE so

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#RevealFrenchStage1Ex1");
```

should only return ONE button. If you change them to

```
<button class="RevealToggle" data-stage="1Ex1">
```

then you can use

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".RevealToggle");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
//      var answers = document.querySelectorAll(".Answer" + this.getAttribute("data-stage"));
//      for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
//        answers[i].style.display = answers[i].style.display == "inline" ? "none" : "inline";
//      }
        var answer = document.querySelector("#Answer" + this.getAttribute("data-stage"));
        answer.style.display = answer.style.display == "inline" ? "none" : "inline";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="FrenchAnswerAlign">
      <h6><button class="RevealToggle" data-stage="1Ex1">Reveal Answer</button></h6>
      <div class="answer" id="Answer1Ex1">
        <ul>
          <li><p>le passeport</p></li>
          <li><p>l'hôtel</p></li>
          <li><p>la valise</p></li>
          <li><p>une station</p></li>
          <li><p>une leçon</p></li>
          <li><p>un chéquier</p></li>
          <li><p>une personne</p></li>
          <li><p>les journalistes</p></li>
          <li><p>les prix</p></li>
          <li><p>de la bière</p></li>
          <li><p>du vin</p></li>
          <li><p>des lettres</p></li>
          <li><p>des autobus</p></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="FrenchAnswerAlign">
      <h6><button class="RevealToggle" data-stage="1Ex2">Reveal Answer</button></h6>
      <div class="answer" id="Answer1Ex2">
        <ul>
          <li><p>le passeport</p></li>
          <li><p>l'hôtel</p></li>
          <li><p>la valise</p></li>
          <li><p>une station</p></li>
          <li><p>une leçon</p></li>
          <li><p>un chéquier</p></li>
          <li><p>une personne</p></li>
          <li><p>les journalistes</p></li>
          <li><p>les prix</p></li>
          <li><p>de la bière</p></li>
          <li><p>du vin</p></li>
          <li><p>des lettres</p></li>
          <li><p>des autobus</p></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just edited the html table version of my code (at the very bottom of the page). I'm trying to match it to this really helpful javascript code. Would you have an idea for the html ID I would put in the answer's <ul> which the script would toggle?

Comment: Same as before. Class Answer1ex1 for the first one

Comment: im trying to match the html to your javascript. would the thing that you are toggling is display style have class=Answer or class=Answer1Ex1

Comment: I would not personally user a table. But see the update. I am now using the ID instead of a class since I am only revealing ONE div and not a set of answer